# Recursive query takes too much time to load data in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-webapi, recursive-query, recursive-datastructures

*I have written a recursive query to get unlimited menu layer. The query works fine providing the exact results but it takes too much time to load. It takes probably 10 to 15 seconds. Please  help me if I need to do anything to improve the performance. I have provided all the code to find out the problem. for mapping from entity to view model I have used automapper. *

**Entity:**

```
public class Menus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Parents")]
        public int? ParentsId { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public bool? Permitted { get; set; }
        public Menus Parents { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Menus> Subs { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MenusRole> MenusRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

**Query:**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Menus>> GetAllMenusAsync()
        {
            List<Menus> temp = await ApplicationDbContext
                .Menus
                .Include(x => x.Subs)
                .Where(x => x.Parents == null)
                .Select(f => new Menus
                {
                    Id = f.Id,
                    Key = f.Key,
                    Label = f.Label,
                    To = f.To,
                    Icon = f.Icon,
                    ParentsId = f.ParentsId,
                    Subs = f.Subs
                }).ToListAsync();
            return Get_all_menus(temp);
        }


public List<Menus> Get_all_menus(List<Menus> menus)
        {
            int z = 0;
            List<Menus> menuList = new List<Menus>();
            if (menus.Count > 0)
            {
                menuList.AddRange(menus);
            }
            foreach (Menus item in menus)
            {
                Menus menu = ApplicationDbContext
                    .Menus
                    .Include(y => y.Subs)
                    .Where(y => y.Id == item.Id)
                    .Select(y => new Menus
                    {
                        Id = y.Id,
                        Key = y.Key,
                        Label = y.Label,
                        To = y.To,
                        Icon = y.Icon,
                        ParentsId = y.ParentsId,
                        Subs = y.Subs,
                        Permitted = true
                    }).First();

                if (menu.Subs == null)
                {
                    z++;
                    continue;
                }

                List<Menus> subMenu = menu.Subs.ToList();
                menu.Subs = Get_all_menus(subMenu);
                menuList[z] = menu;
                z++;
            }
            return menuList;
        }
```

**In Controller**

```
 [HttpGet("get-all-menus")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllMenus()
        {
            var menus = await _menusService.GetAllMenus();
            var menusResources = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Menus>, IEnumerable<MenusResourceForSidebar>>(menus);
            return Ok(menusResources);
        }
```

**View Model**

```
public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public bool? Permitted { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MenusResourceForSidebar> Subs { get; set; }
```

Comment: IMHO just `context.Menus.ToList();` and the change tracker will sort out the navigations for you. Otherwise you'll need to resort to raw sql https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/recursive-data-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of loading the root menus, then loading the children in separate queries, just load the whole collection in one query, and then populate the navigation links afterwards.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Menus>> GetAllMenusAsync()
{
    List<Menus> temp = await ApplicationDbContext.Menus.ToList();
    List<Menus> topLevel = new List<Menu>();

    foreach (var menu in temp)
    {
        if (menu.ParentsId == null)
        {
            topLevel.Add(menu);
            continue;
        }

        var parent = temp.Find(x => x.Id == temp.ParentsId.Value);
        if (parent.Subs == null)
            parent.Subs = new List<Menus>();

        parent.Subs.Add(menu);
    }

    return topLevel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do:

```
context.Menus.Include(m => m.Subs).ToList();
```

The relationship fixup in EFCore will link all the menus together in a tree for you. In later EFs you don't even need the Include..

```
context.Menus.ToList();
```

Here is a table in SSMS:

[image]

Here is the data:

[image]

Here it is chopped up in a paint program and rearranged into a tree:

[image]

Here's the scaffolded entity:

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp7net5.Models
{
    public partial class Menu
    {
        public Menu()
        {
            InverseParent = new HashSet<Menu>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }

        public virtual Menu Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Menu> InverseParent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's what we see after asking EFC (5, in my case) to download it all with just a ToList:

[image]

Of course it might make sense to start with a root (or multiple roots but my data only has one)

[image]

---

Don't give classes plural names (Menus), btw, and don't give properties plural names if they aren't collections/enumerables (Parents) - it makes for very confusing code

Comment: To load whole menu you have to do a lot of Includes `context.Menus.Include(m => m.Subs).ThenInclude(m => m.Subs).ThenInclude(m => m.Subs).ThenInclude(m => m.Subs).ThenInclude(m => m.Subs)` Performance should be better but still terrible.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that's just not true... If it's your downvote, do please reconsider it; i've edited the post to include a demonstration. I'm also keen to know (because you're very EF knowledgeable) if you think there's something I missed.. You only have to do that ThenInclude if you aren't downloading the whole tree or you cannot form a query that loads an entire wanted tree segment in one hit

Comment: Ok, this make sense. EF should fixup loaded entities.

Comment: Wow, I was not aware that Entity Framework could handle trees!

Comment: If you think about it, it does an awful lot of tree work - Customer has Orders has Products has Components.. but I know what you mean. Wiring up self referential nodes isn't so different to wiring up customers that have orders etc - there's just one big blat of data from the db that is then linked together in a similar way to how your answer does. If you were to represent the path in the db somehow (hierarchy Id, or even just a varchar that is like a file path) then it could do quite well just saying  `Folders.Where(f => f.Path like "C:\temp\%"` - it's the "one hit" that is needed